# Is SELECT DISTINCT bad practice when you know a join will produce duplicates?

Tags: sql

On occasion when building a query I know I will have duplicates due to one of the joined tables. Is it better practice to remove those duplicates using a more rigorous join statement and/or using SELECT DISTINCT in a subquery, rather than using a SELECT DISTINCT statement for the entire thing?

For example:

```
SELECT PL.STATION,
PL.PART_NUMBER,
PD.DESCRIPTION
FROM SAMPLE_DB.PART_LOCATOR PL
LEFT JOIN PROD_SAMPLE_DB.PART_DETAIL PD
ON PL.PART_NUMBER = PD.PART_NUMBER
WHERE PL.PART_NUMBER = '4077968'
AND PL.STATION = 'ATL'

4 rows returned.
```

[image]

Obviously I could just use a SELECT DISTINCT to get unique values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PL.STATION,
PL.PART_NUMBER,
PD.DESCRIPTION
FROM SAMPLE_DB.PART_LOCATOR PL
LEFT JOIN PROD_SAMPLE_DB.PART_DETAIL PD
ON PL.PART_NUMBER = PD.PART_NUMBER
WHERE PL.PART_NUMBER = '4077968'
AND PL.STATION = 'ATL'

1 row returned.
```

But is this better form (making the join more specific)?

```
SELECT PL.STATION,
PL.PART_NUMBER,
PD.DESCRIPTION
FROM SAMPLE_DB.PART_LOCATOR PL
LEFT JOIN PROD_SAMPLE_DB.PART_DETAIL PD
ON PL.PART_NUMBER = PD.PART_NUMBER
AND PL.BIN_NUMBER = PD.BIN_NUMBER     <--- Additional join criteria
WHERE PL.PART_NUMBER = '4077968'
AND PL.STATION = 'ATL'

1 row returned.
```

Or this:

```
SELECT PL.STATION,
PL.PART_NUMBER,
PD.DESCRIPTION
FROM SAMPLE_DB.PART_LOCATOR PL
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT     <--- Add distinct statement in subquery
    PART_NUMBER,
    DESCRIPTION
    FROM
    PROD_SAMPLE_DB.PART_DETAIL
) PD
ON PL.PART_NUMBER = PD.PART_NUMBER
WHERE PL.PART_NUMBER = '4077968'
AND PL.STATION = 'ATL'

1 row returned.
```

What is considered best practice?

Comment: Not sure if we can talk about best practice. My only concern would be performance. So you should test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see the performance. The second one create a temporal table so the JOIN wont use the index. So I probably go with first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is necessarily a **best practice** in this case.  Typically, you always want your join semantics to match the logical representation of your data and the desired result.  In other words, if logically the join criteria should be across multiple columns because this is how part descriptions logically relate to a part, then that is what you should do.

Otherwise, I always default to what is more readable from a query perspective and how the query will perform.  Placing the `DISTINCT` inside a sub-query results in a somewhat bloated query for others to try and understand.  Also, the DBMS might even perform worse from a performance perspective with the sub-query approach since it could cause indexes to be eliminated).

Obviously, I don't understand your data model, but each of these queries could actually produce different results depending on how a part description is logically associated to a part.

It appears that a part description is associated to a part based on both a part number and bin number (this fact is based on the structure of the `PART_DETAIL` table).  However, in this specific case, all part numbers (but with different bin numbers) happen to have the same part description.

What if the descriptions were not the same (e.g. different for each part number/bin number combination).  Then only your more specific join would return the correct results (e.g. the part description for a specific part).  So again, it all goes back to writing your query such that the logic used matches the logical representation of your data and the result set you are looking for.

This is just my 2 cents.

Comment: Another way of saying this, `you always want your join semantics to logically match what you are trying to do`, is this, `make sure you get the proper results.`

Comment: That is true, but there could be lots of ways to get the proper results.  The point I was trying to make is that the join should logically represent the question the query is trying to answer.  e.g. if you want a part description but it's description is associated to both a part number and bin number (like in the example) then that is how you should perform the join instead of arriving to the proper results indirectly (using `DISTINCT` or otherwise)

Answer (score 5):

There is a best practice.  If this is the query that you intend, then use it!

```
SELECT PL.STATION, PL.PART_NUMBER, PD.DESCRIPTION
FROM SAMPLE_DB.PART_LOCATOR PL LEFT JOIN
     PROD_SAMPLE_DB.PART_DETAIL PD
     ON PL.PART_NUMBER = PD.PART_NUMBER AND
         PL.BIN_NUMBER = PD.BIN_NUMBER     <--- Additional join criteria
WHERE PL.PART_NUMBER = '4077968' AND PL.STATION = 'ATL';
```

As a general rule, `SELECT DISTINCT` incurs a fair amount of overhead for the query.  Hence, you should avoid it or use it sparingly.  The idea of generating duplicate rows using `JOIN` just to remove them with `SELECT DISTINCT` is rather reminiscent of Sisyphus pushing a rock up a hill, only to have it roll back down again.

That doesn't mean that you *shouldn't* use it when appropriate.

Conclusion:  If adding one or more join conditions does what you want, then that is the best thing to do.

Otherwise, doing the `DISTINCT` *before* the `JOIN` is likely to be a good idea.  However, there are exceptions to this rule.  Doing the `DISTINCT` *after* the `JOIN` makes sense under some circumstances:

- There are  duplicates but not very many (implying that the intermediate result set is not very large much larger than the unique'd version).
- The `WHERE` clause is highly selective (meaning that removing the unique elements in a subquery wastes a lot of effort on rows that are not in the final result set).

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider the use of `DISTINCT` a bad practice. For example, sometimes a result set between a parent record and its child records can produce duplicated rows.

This is specially true if you don't work with surrogate keys, since those will forcely distinguish rows even if all the other columns have the same value. Of course, if you do have surrogate keys in your model, omitting them from the `SELECT` clause may also produce duplicated rows in the result.

If you don't want duplicates in that case, you can quickly eliminate them by using the `DISTINCT` keyword. It's simple and efficient, even though can be replaced by a `GROUP BY` clause (which can be dull to apply when there're too many columns). Most database engines will choose an optimal execution plan, so `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` will perform equally well.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
SELECT PL.STATION,
PL.PART_NUMBER,
PD.DESCRIPTION
FROM SAMPLE_DB.PART_LOCATOR PL
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT     <--- Add distinct statement in subquery
    PART_NUMBER,
    DESCRIPTION
    FROM
    PROD_SAMPLE_DB.PART_DETAIL
) PD
ON PL.PART_NUMBER = PD.PART_NUMBER
WHERE PL.PART_NUMBER = '4077968'
AND PL.STATION = 'ATL'
```

It is more readable and more efficient

Comment: It actually might not be more efficient  If there is an index on `PART_NUMBER` then using the sub-query could cause the DBMS to ignore it...resulting in a less efficient query.  Perhaps `PART_DETAIL` has a compound index on `PART_NUMBER` and `BIN_NUMBER` and using a `DISTINCT` sub-query instead of a join on both fields would also cause the index not to be used.  It just all depends on how the data is supposed to be logically represented.